# How to Solve Too Much Recursion Error For An Element Appended To List of Gallery Images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code below which monitors when a gallery loads images (this is done via JavaScript). Then it counts the total amount of images loaded then subtract the amount that is already visible (with CSS we hide all images then show only the first 4). On the 4th visible image we would like to show the remainder (number of hidden images) with the text "view more". For example a total of 34 images with only 4 visible and 30 hidden on the 4th visible image we show "30 View more"

```
// When gallery div is loaded/inserted 
jQuery('.mapsvg-controller-view').on('DOMNodeInserted','.mapsvg-gallery-wrap', function() {  
        
            var galleryFigureNum = 0;
            var moreImagesNum = 0;
    
            // Count the total number of figure elements (images) 
            jQuery('.mapsvg-gallery > figure').each(function(){
                galleryFigureNum++;
            });
            
            // Subtract the amount of already visible images from the total available
            moreImagesNum = galleryFigureNum - 4;
    
            // Add more available images number and text to 4th figure
            jQuery('.mapsvg-gallery').children().eq(3).append('<div>'+moreImagesNum+'More Position 4</div>');
    });
```

The problem I have is I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion

Which is produced by this line:

```
jQuery('.mapsvg-gallery').children().eq(3).append('<div>'+moreImagesNum+'More Position 4</div>');
```

This is causing the **`<div>`** to be inserted multiple times (239+).

How can I solve the **too much recursion** error? I only want **`<div>`** to be added once.

**Note:** using **append** or **after** produces the same error.

Comment: You're appending content to an element within the `DOMNodeInserted` event handler of said element. That's why there is recursion. You need to not do that. Without seeing the full context of your code, or a clear explanation of your goal, we can't really offer any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.mapsvg-gallery').children().eq(3).append('<div>'+moreImagesNum+'More Position 4</div>');
});
```

This line is adding an element to the div that you're listening to, which re-triggers the `DOMNodeInserted` event, which re-adds the "more" div, which re-triggers the `DOMNodeInserted`....

You need to move your "more" message outside of the div that you're listening to, or more likely not listen to the `DOMNodeInserted` altogether - you know when your images are loaded, and ideally how many of them there are

Comment: Thanks for your help I was able to place the "more" div outside the DOMNodeInserted and reposition the text with CSS. It works as I want it too thanks again.